# How to provide a boolean flag for JavaScript files injected into a web page's frame?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I currently have a javascript file that is injected declaratively through the manifest.

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://example.com/*"],
  "all_frames": true,
  "js": ["doubleClickScript.js"]
}
```

]

doubleclickScript.js currently detects a double click within a frame.

```
window.addEventListener('dblclick', dblclickCheck);
```

The event checks if text is double clicked on and then via a `window.parent.document.dispatchEvent` it sends the text back to the contentscript.js of the extension.

I would now like to create an option to turn this double click on and off.  Which leads me to my question as how to best do this.

I realise I could use a custom event or window.postMessage each time this file is injected but this seems to be inefficient especially as there are 5 frames on the page which are changing all the time.

Ultimately is it possible to somehow have the following where I can set flag from the content script to true or false?

```
if (flag) window.addEventListener('dblclick', dblclickCheck);
```

I am adding the javascript tag as this also might be a pure javascript question as well.

Comment: You could store your flag using [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), which is accessible from content scripts, and read it before adding your double-click listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to write how I solved this problem. I felt it important for the Google searchers landing here.

I had one major understanding problem as I did not read or understand [exactly what Google meant on content scripts.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).  If you "inject" your JS file as I did declaratively as below, then your js file is loaded as you wish but it is still only a content extension powers.

```
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["http://example.com/*"],
"all_frames": true,
"js": ["doubleClickScript.js"]
}
```

So the above doubleClickScript.js cannot read web page variables and can only read and write the HTML etc which [is listed here under Content Script Capabilities.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#capabilities) and communication with other content scripts is not easy in my opinion.  Thus at the end of the day the above file doubleClickScript.js could also just be in your content.js file as well. The difference is that doubleClickScript.js is only injected in my case when a frame is loaded (this is nice). Further a reference to document would be the frame document.  In a standard content.js file you would have to first get this specific frame and document before you use any code. Here is the main problem because you need to know when the frame has loaded and everything is ready.

If you want your java-script file to not be disabled by the extension rules then you need to do the following "injection".  I believe this is also called injecting the file but once this is loaded it will be able to read the webpages javascript etc.

```
var dblclickscript = document.createElement('script');
dblclickscript.src = chrome.extension.getURL('doubleClickScript.js');
dblclickscript.id = 'dblclickscript';
dblclickscript.type = 'text/javascript';
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(dblclickscript);
```

After understanding this I could work on my problem. @IvanNokonoko is correct in showing one solution.  As i was effectively injecting content scripts into each frame I could use the chrome.storage.  I have however taken probably a more complicated method.

In my main content script I add a new script tag to the websites main/top document's head. This has variables in it. This script has an id so I can find it again.  If the variables change then I use the id to delete this script and put it back again.

Then from my doubleClickScript.js each time it loads it also loads a script tag to the frames document head. This script uses window.parent.##### to know what variable values are and in my case if one was true then an eventlistent is added.

This eventlistener calls a custom event which is being listened to by my main contentscript.

This is a little more complicated than just using the storage but I already was injecting script into script tags so this was what I wanted to stick with.